# Angular 7 image links working on local host but do not work when uploaded to server

Tags: html, angular, image, angular7

Can anyone help me understand why ***only*** the second of these following image links would work? I've cleared the cache and every other idea I could think of over the last several hours. 
Clearly the image is available in the assets folder since the second one is working.
Any help is appreciated

```
<div style="float: right;" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <img src="../assets/images/TherapyRoomOpt.JPG" style="width:100%;" class="img-rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive box-shadow" />
        <img src="../assets/images/IMG_1014.JPG" style="width:100%;" class="img-rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive box-shadow" />
        <div class='margin-top'>
          <app-services></app-services>
        </div>
        <img src="../assets/images/IMG_1014.jpg" style="width:100%;" class="img-rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive box-shadow" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Try  to change the width, it seems like both of the images might be overlapping as both of them have 100%width. Also, check the console for any errors.

Comment: you may need to go into more details on your build / deploy process to the server.  can you guarantee the file is there on the server? or is it just case sensitive about the .JPG

Comment: I'm building to a subfolder using the ng build --prod --base-href method. The app works, except for 2 images. I've quadruple checked the assets folder and the file is there. I've tried changing the case and have copy/pasted in the path.

There is a place holder for the missing img so it doesn't seem they'd be overlapping. And I DO get an error for the missing file/files

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same issue, locally it was working but after deploying the images were not showing. Solution is simple.
change : /src/assets/images/yourImage.jpg to
assets/images/commitment.jpg

and re-deploy. All the best.

Answer (score -1):

it looks like it must be case sensitive about the capital .JPG

```
<img src="../assets/images/IMG_1014.JPG"
```

vs

```
<img src="../assets/images/IMG_1014.jpg"
```

or double check that the path is correct and that the file is on the deployed server where you expect it to be.

Also make sure you dont have `"../"` confused with `"./"`
:)

Comment: Actually this did fix the issue for Image 3. Unfortunately Image 1 is the one I'm having the issue with and that's still not working. I'm going to try copying the image with a new name. maybe the image link is somehow cached incorrectly..?

Comment: you could try in incognito mode or another browser to verify.

Comment: are you still having the same issue?

Comment: Hi, I did eventually figure this out. My img src was pointing to the assets/images folder on the root. Since the images that were deployed to the subfolder (test) were new, they were not in the root folder. The fix was to remove one of the periods.
`<img src="./assets/images/IMG_1014.JPG"`

Comment: ahhhh.  that period issue gets me a lot also.  glad you got it figured out!!  thanks for the update!!

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that the image links were pointing to the root and since the images that I was building to the subfolder were new, they weren't in the root folder. The fix was to remove one of the periods from the img link

`<img src="./assets/images/IMG_1014.JPG"`